# Limit video duration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, video

On my ROR site I need to show limited video preview (i.e. 20 sec for guests and full video for members).

I know just one way to solve this. When video uploaded, create two versions: short for previews and long (original). And if user is guest then show short version in video player. Otherwise show full version.

But, thought its a freaky solution. Maybe there is better way? More elegant. E.g. limitation with http protocol or streaming.. I dont know.

And ofc solution should be server-side not client-side.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution you have mentioned is the last way of doing it in rails.